# Imorting procedure in PostrgeSQL

Tags: postgresql

The objective is to import and use procedure in PostgreSQL (via pgAdmin and Shell). My experiment's with the task ended with mistake [screen of mistake here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxQw4.png).

Example of code (from tutorials):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_event(
                                      title text, 
                                      starts TIMESTAMP,
                                      ends TIMESTAMP, 
                                      venue text, 
                                      postal VARCHAR(9), 
                                      country CHAR(2) 
                                      )
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
AS $$
DECLARE
    did_insert BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    found_count INTEGER;
    the_venue_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT venue_id INTO the_venue_id
    FROM venues v
    WHERE v.postal_code=postal 
                  AND v.country_code=country 
                  AND v.name LIKE venue
    LIMIT 1;

    IF the_venue_id IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO venues (name, postal_code, country_code)
        VALUES (venue, postal, country)

        RETURNING venue_id INTO the_venue_id;
        did_insert := TRUE;
    END IF;

RAISE NOTICE ‘Venue found %’, the_venue_id;

INSERT INTO events (title, starts, ends, venue_id)
VALUES (title, starts, ends, the_venue_id);

RETURN did_insert;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please post the error text into the question instead of an image.  This makes it easier for us to help you, and also indexes the error message for searching.

Answer (score 1):

In your function builder (I guess pgAdmin) you have set language to `SQL`, but in actual function definition you have `plpgsql`, with is correct choice. You just need to change in pgAdmin what language is function written in or simple paste it into query window and execute (works just fine).

EDIT: Actually, you likely have put too much in `code` section, since pgAdmin is likely filling a lot of it for you. If you go to `SQL` tab you will see actual query that pgAdmin is attempting to execute and I'm sure it is nothing good. My recommendation would be to just execute `code` as plain SQL in SQL Editor (or whatever it is called).